# ncurses ライブラリ　PADを描画がする方法が知りたい

Tags: c++

提示コードの最下部の`void Screen::Renderer()const`関数部ですがなぜ`werase(window);`関数で画面を削除して`wrefresh(window);`関数で再描画しているのにもかかわらず描画されないのでしょうか？ 色んなサイトを調べてリファレンスを確認しましたがどうしてもわかりません。
※window変数が`PAD`です。

参考サイト：　[http://www5d.biglobe.ne.jp/~kobamasa/comp/Linux/tips/curses.html](http://www5d.biglobe.ne.jp/%7Ekobamasa/comp/Linux/tips/curses.html)

Github: https://github.com/Shigurechan/AsciiArtEditor

###### Screen.cpp

```cpp
#include "../header/Screen.hpp"


#include "../header/Character.hpp"
#include "../header/Color.hpp"
#include "../header/Vector.hpp"



//　######################## コンストラクタ ######################## 
Screen::Screen(int x,int y,int xMin,int yMin,int xMax,int yMax)
{

      //ウインドウ初期化
    //getmaxyx(stdscr,windowSize.y,windowSize.x);
    window = newpad(yMax - yMin,xMax - xMin);
    //prefresh(window,posY,posX,posY,posX,posY + sizeY,posX + sizeX);
    prefresh(window,y,x,yMin,xMin,yMax,xMax);

      position.x = x;
      position.y = y;

      size.x = xMax - xMin;
      size.y = yMax - yMin;
      
      maxSize = size.x * size.y;

      stage = std::make_unique<std::vector<Character>>(size.x * size.y);
      
      for(std::vector<Character>::iterator itr = stage->begin(); itr != stage->end(); itr++)
      {
            itr->chr = ' ';
            itr->color = GetColorNum(2,2);
            itr->type = 0;
      }
}


//　######################## 移動 ########################
void Screen::Move(int x,int y)
{
      position.x = x;
      position.y = y;

    prefresh(window,position.y,position.x,position.y,position.x,position.y + size.y,position.x + size.x);       
}


//　######################## 画面サイズ更新 ########################
void Screen::UpdateScreen()
{

}



//　######################## Update ########################
void Screen::Update()
{
      
}

//　######################## 文字設定 ######################## 
void Screen::Input(int x,int y,Character c)
{
      stage->at((y * size.x) + x) = c;
}

//　######################## 文字削除 ######################## 
void Screen::Delete(int x,int y)
{
      stage->at((y * size.x) + x).chr = ' ';
      stage->at((y * size.x) + x).color = 0;
      stage->at((y * size.x) + x).type = 0;
}

//　######################## Renderer ######################## 
void Screen::Renderer()const
{
      //clear();
      werase(window);
      //erase();

      for(int y = 0; y < size.y; y++)
      {
            for(int x = 0; x < size.x; x++)
            {
                  wattron(window,COLOR_PAIR(stage->at((y * size.x) + x).color));

                  mvwaddch(window,position.y + y,position.x + x,stage->at((y * size.x) + x).chr);
                  
                  wattroff(window,COLOR_PAIR(stage->at((y * size.x) + x).color));

            }
      }

      wrefresh(window); //描画
      //refresh();

}

//　######################## デストラクタ ######################## 
Screen::~Screen()
{


}
```

###### Edit.cpp

```cpp
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "../lib/ncurses/include/curses.h"

#include "../header/Log.hpp"
#include "../header/Vector.hpp"
#include "../header/Edit.hpp"
#include "../header/Screen.hpp"
#include "../header/Entry.hpp"
#include "../header/Character.hpp"
#include "../header/Color.hpp"
#include "../header/SaveMenu.hpp"


#define HOLD_FRAME ((int) 30)

#define ESC_KEY ((int)27)


//　######################## コンストラクタ ######################## 
Edit::Edit(Entry* e) : Scene(e)
{
    holdPressed = 0;

    position.x = 0;
    position.y = 0;
    
    drawCharacter.chr = '@';
    drawCharacter.color = 0;
    drawCharacter.type = 0;


    canvasPosition.x = 20;
    canvasPosition.y = 10;



    //Print("%d\n",sizeof(drawCharacter));

    canvas = std::make_unique<Screen>(canvasPosition.x,canvasPosition.y,canvasPosition.x,canvasPosition.y,canvasPosition.x + 10,canvasPosition.y + 10); //前景


    saveMenu = std::make_unique<SaveMenu>(Scene::Menu_Sequence::Save,100,100,10,0);
}

//　######################## Keyboard Input ######################## 
void Edit::KeyInput()
{
    int key = getch();
    switch(key)
    {
        case KEY_LEFT:
        {
            position.x--;
            canvasPosition.x--;

        }
        break;

        case KEY_RIGHT:
        {
            position.x++;
            canvasPosition.x++;
        }
        break;

        case KEY_DOWN:
        {
            canvasPosition.y++;

            position.y++;
        }
        break;

        case KEY_UP:
        {
            canvasPosition.y--;

            position.y--;
        }
        break;
    }


    //書き込み
    if(key == ' ')
    {
        canvas->Input(position.x,position.y,drawCharacter); 
    }
    




    //ESCで終了
    if(key == ESC_KEY)
    {
        entry->ChangeScene(Scene::Sequence::Exit);
    }
}

//　######################## Update ######################## 
void Edit::Update()
{
    canvas->Move(canvasPosition.x,canvasPosition.y);
    


    MouseInput();   //マウス入力
    KeyInput();     //キー入力

    move(position.y,position.x);    //カーソル移動
}

//　######################## Renderer ######################## 
void Edit::Renderer()const
{

    canvas->Renderer(); //キャンバス

    

    //saveMenu->Renderer();
}


//　######################## Mouse Input ######################## 
void Edit::MouseInput()
{
    
    //マウス移動イベント
    if(getmouse(&mouseEvent) == OK)
    {
        //マウス座標
        if(mouseEvent.bstate & REPORT_MOUSE_POSITION)
        {
            position.x = mouseEvent.x;
            position.y = mouseEvent.y;
        }           
    }
    

    //長押し判定
    if(prevClickEvent.bstate & BUTTON1_PRESSED)
    {
        holdPressed++;
        if(holdPressed > HOLD_FRAME)
        {
            prevClickEvent.bstate = BUTTON1_PRESSED;
            canvas->Input(position.x,position.y,drawCharacter);
            holdPressed = HOLD_FRAME + 1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        prevClickEvent.bstate = 0;
        holdPressed = 0;
    }
    

    //クリックイベント
    if(getmouse(&clickEvent) == OK)
    {
        //Left Click
        if(clickEvent.bstate & BUTTON1_PRESSED )
        {
            prevClickEvent.bstate = BUTTON1_PRESSED;
            canvas->Input(position.x,position.y,drawCharacter);
        }       
        else if(clickEvent.bstate & BUTTON1_RELEASED)
        {
            prevClickEvent.bstate = 0;
        }       
        else if(clickEvent.bstate & BUTTON1_CLICKED)
        {
        }       
        else if(clickEvent.bstate & BUTTON1_DOUBLE_CLICKED)
        {
        }       
        else if(clickEvent.bstate & BUTTON1_TRIPLE_CLICKED)
        {
        }       
        

        //Right Click
        if(clickEvent.bstate & BUTTON1_PRESSED)
        {
        }       
        else if(clickEvent.bstate & BUTTON1_RELEASED)
        {
        }               
        else if(clickEvent.bstate & BUTTON1_DOUBLE_CLICKED)
        {
        }           
        else if(clickEvent.bstate & BUTTON1_TRIPLE_CLICKED)
        {
        }       
        else if(clickEvent.bstate & BUTTON1_CLICKED)
        {
        }       
    }
    

}

//　######################## Loop ######################## 
void Edit::Loop()
{
    Update();
    Renderer();
}



//　######################## デストラクタ ######################## 
Edit::~Edit()
{

}
```

Comment: [tag:c++cli]のWikiを記載しました。本件とは無関係と思われるため、タグ指定を外しておきます。

Comment: AIX 関連の文書になりますが、[curses 環境内のウィンドウ](https://www.ibm.com/docs/ja/aix/7.2?topic=library-windows-in-curses-environment) に「ただし、 newwin, subwin, **wrefresh** および wnoutrefresh サブルーチンを除きます。 これらのサブルーチンの代わりに、newpad, subpad, **prefresh** および pnoutrefresh の各サブルーチンを使用します。」という記述があります。

Comment: マルチポスト https://teratail.com/questions/360538